# In electron since the 'remote' has been deprecated, what module to use in place of it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to make a video recording app using electron js as per this video from fireship - https://youtu.be/3yqDxhR2XxE and I'm stuck at building a selection menu of available video sources, as it turned out that the `"remote"` module has been deprecated. I have 2 js files, one is `index.js` which is the main electron js file and the other is the `render.js` file (in which I'm building functions for my app). I tried importing `"remote"` module in the `index.js` file but that didn't work. I even set the `enableRemoteModule: true` in `webPreferences` in `index.js`  but that too didn't work. Now I am completely out of ideas as a newbie. I heard about the
`ipcRenderer` and `ipcMain` modules but not sure they will work.

> **Below is the code for my "app.js":**

```js
//Buttons
const videoElement = document.querySelector('Video');
const startBtn = document.getElementById('startBtn');
const stopBtn = document.getElementById('stopBtn');
const videoSelectBtn = document.getElementById('videoSelectBtn');
videoSelectBtn.onclick = getVideoSources;


const {
  desktopCapturer
} = require("electron");
const {
  remote
} = require('@electron/remote')
const {
  Menu
} = remote


//Getting all available Video Sources
async function getVideoSources() {
  const inputSources = await desktopCapturer.getSources({
    types: ['window', 'screen']
  });

  const videoOptionsMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(
    inputSources.map(source => {
      return {
        label: source.name,
        click: () => selectSource(source)
      };
    })
  );

  videoOptionsMenu.popup();
}
```

Comment: remote module is meant to be used in renderer process,  in renderer.js file in your case .https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/remote.

Comment: https://nornagon.medium.com/electrons-remote-module-considered-harmful-70d69500f31

Comment: @srinivast6 yes i read this enitre document earlier, but if you know how can I use other modules like the ipcMain/ipcRenderer modules in my file then please let me know

Comment: the blogpost spring linked to has an example. Also, you can look at the [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main)